# Gving constraints to two views with code in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to give constraints to two views that were created in storyboard. I want them to be bigger or smaller by the size of the screen. What I'm trying to is that I give the same height and width to each view and pin them to the view. I think I did something wrong. I don't see any views after I run it on simulator. Any help would be appreciated. thank you.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var topView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var secondBottomView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


             topView.isHidden = false
             topView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
             topView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
             topView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondBottomView.topAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
             topView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
             topView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
             topView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondBottomView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
             topView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondBottomView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true

             secondBottomView.isHidden = false
             secondBottomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
             secondBottomView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
             secondBottomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.topAnchor, constant:-10).isActive = true
             secondBottomView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
             secondBottomView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
             secondBottomView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
             secondBottomView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
}


}
```

Comment: Did you get any constraints error in the console?

Comment: @Swat it says... Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
 Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
 Try this: 
  (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
  (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
topView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
```

with

```
topView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
```

And this

```
secondBottomView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
secondBottomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.topAnchor, constant:-10).isActive = true
```

with only

```
secondBottomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant:-10).isActive = true
```